# H1 NMR Spectra of inorganic complex, Cu4OCl6(2-mepy)4

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I'm having difficult interpreting the following H<sup>1</sup> NMR I have been given for Cu<sub>4</sub>OCl<sub>6</sub>(2-mepy)<sub>4</sub>.

[image]

The NMR spectra obtained with integration trace beneath. I'm not too sure how to rationalise the 4.5:1 ratio between the peaks nor the cause of the small broad peak at 115ppm (well to the left of the spectra).

[image]

I'm also not too sure why the H1 NMR range is so vast. I appreciate being bonded to metals the electron density is changed across the relevant proton environments but by that much?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is a typical example of an H NMR spectrum of a paramagnetic compound. The formal oxidation state of the Cu here is Cu(II) resulting in d9 configuration. This means that there will be an unpaired d electron making the Cu atoms paramagnetic.

The lone electron in the Cu atoms disturbs the magnetic field the Hs' feel resulting in extreme chemical shifts and also provide a very efficient relaxation mechanism resulting in extreme peak broadening (in some cases you cant even see the resonances at all). The highest paramagnetic shift I have encountered so far was around 250 ppm for an Fe(II) complex I made. In another occasion we had resonances at 1200 ppm!

As for the peak broadening I had peaks of ν1/2 of a few thousands of Hz. The integration wont always make much sense with paramagnetic compounds either.